# Postman - Nested Environment Variables

Tags: postman

I'm looking for a way to make environment variables in Postman, that contain other variables. For example: {Server}=localhost;{Port}=9200;{ServerUrl}={Server}:{Port}.

Like in Make...

This way it doesn't seem to work with Postman.

EDIT:

My attempt:
[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, that just using `{{ElasticsearchServer}}://{{blah}}:{{blah}}` straight into the URL doesn't?

Comment: Lazyness. Putting in one variable instead of three

Comment: Why not just put the full URL in one variable then, instead of slicing it up? If that's for using different values, on different environments, that's what the whole point of environment files are for anyway - Keep one variable in place on the URL and then select a different environment to point too.

Comment: So I assume the answer to my question is 'no'? :)

Comment: Your way would work...If you used the correct syntax. `{{ElasticsearchProtocol}}://{{ElasticsearchServer}}:{{ElasticsearchPort}}` but I just think you're missing the point of the environment file and you could just add that string to a single variable and just use that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do it but I wouldn't recommend it, just seem like you're missing the benefit creating a set of variables and then changing the values of these by selecting a different environment file.

Add this string `{{ElasticsearchProtocol}}://{{ElasticsearchServer}}:{{ElasticsearchPort}}` as the `ElasiticsearchUrl` variable, on the environment file.

[image: Postman URL]

Or you could add this to the `Pre-Request Script`:

```
let ElasticsearchProtocol   = pm.environment.get('ElasticsearchProtocol')
let ElasticsearchServer     = pm.environment.get('ElasticsearchServer')
let ElasticsearchPort       = pm.environment.get('ElasticsearchPort')

pm.environment.set("ElasticsearchUrl", `${ElasticsearchProtocol}://${ElasticsearchServer}:${ElasticsearchPort}`)
```

[image: Postman Pre Request]

Comment: Okay so nested variables work with double brackets! That was the answer I was looking for. Accepted ;)

Comment: _"just seem like you're missing the benefit creating a set of variables and then changing the values of these by selecting a **different environment file**"_ - I agree with that use case but what the OP is describing isn't mutually exclusive.  It can be useful to describe a _composite value_ by joining the values of other variables, wherever they may come from.  DevOps is the same.  e.g. `dropRootFolder = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(sourceAlias)/$(dropFolderName)`.  All latter 3 variables are environment specific.